# taking a django site down for maintenance?

Tags: django, nginx, server, gunicorn

I am running django with nginx/gunicorn. I am not deeply familiar with how nginx and gunicorn work, but suppose that I want to take my django site down for maintenance.

I assume I would be wanting to redirect to some simple maintenance page by going into the nginx/gunicorn settings and redirecting something but I could be wrong.

What is the correct (easiest) way to do this?

EDIT adding nginx config proxy statements:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://app_server;
```

EDIT 2: adding nginx sites-enabled file

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/mysite/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/mysite/static_dump;
    }

    location / {
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        #proxy_redirect off;
        #proxy_pass http://app_server;

        if (-f /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html) {
                return 503;
        }
    }
   error_page 503 @maintenance;
   location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to do is to add the maintenance page somewhere in the server, and then in your nginx file ( In the sites-enabled folder) redirect requests to the site to that maintenance page. 
Your nginx page should contain:

```
server_name myhost.example.com;

root /path/to/html/file/directory;
index index.html;
```

Only the above 3 lines are enough

Comment: I tried that but strangely enough it doesn't seem to have an effect even after I restarted the servers. I can't figure out why it is not working

Comment: @deltaskelta Did you remove the proxy-forward to the gunicorn server?

Comment: no, there are four lines in there that I didn't touch...adding them to the main post

Comment: I certainly do have those lines in the nginx config file. Should I remove them? It doesn't seem so

Comment: @deltaskelta The lines that you showed in your question are needed only if you are going to redirect the request. So you can comment them out during maintenance

Comment: I tried commenting them out and adding the if statements and still nothing. I will post the files in the main post

Comment: no error, I just realized I was using my dev environment and not refreshing the production page.........I wasted a good hour or so before figuring that out.