# Django: Temporarily redirect all URLs to one view

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am building site and thought it would be nice to have some sort of maintenance page where I could redirect users if need be.

How can I start redirecting all requests to one specific view? I am using [Constance](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to have maintenance switch in my admin view *(just a bool value)*. Its value is then available thorough the project.

I've already prepared another list of `urlpatterns` but cannot figure out how to dynamically change them so the redirect works.

```
maintenance_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.maintenance, name='maintenance'),
]
```

This is `urls.py` file from app, not the project one which I would leave alone.

I also thought about modifying `base.html` template and rendering "maintenance page" this way, but I think that is pretty bad solution.

EDIT: To clarify. My main question isnt how to write urlpattern that will capture all traffic, but how to edit these dynamically in response to Constance config change. So I can toggle that in admin.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34148903

Answer (score 12):

The regex in your question will only match on `/` (the root of your site). If you want to catch everything, just use `^` only. Every URL has a beginning, so `^` always matches.

```python
url(r'^', views.maintenance, name='maintenance')
```

Of course, this depends upon your normal urlpatterns being disabled in some fashion. It sounds like maybe you have that covered already.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't :-) I have only prepared these other urlpatterns but don't know how to change them after I toggle maintenance in my admin..

Comment: @Filip I think you'd be better off going with a middleware.  Create a boolean setting `MAINTENANCE_MODE` and put your middleware first in the list.  If `MAINTENANCE_MODE` is true, return your static response from the middleware. (You could also do some conditional fiddling with the URLs, but IMO the middleware is much cleaner).  Another option is to perform the static delivery at a higher level than your WSGI server, such as Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

**Implementing maintenance page in django**

add a bool variable in settings.py like this:

```py
MAINTENANCE_MODE = True
```

and in main urls.py file, after all configurations add these lines:

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generics.base import TemplateView

if settings.MAINTENANCE_MODE:
   urlpatterns.insert(0, re_path(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='../path/maintenance.html'), name='maintenance'))
```

if you want turn off the maintenance mode, you have to make **MAINTENANCE_MODE** variable **False** and restart the web-server.